# Connecting to database with GWT after compiling

Tags: java, database, gwt

I am having trouble connecting to a database after compiling the GWT. I am using Eclipse for the development. The server is setup at

```
//database.corp.company.com
```

I have set up my onModuleLoad like this:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    if (databaseService == null) {
        databaseService = GWT.create(DatabaseService.class);
    }

    AsyncCallback<String> callback = new AsyncCallback<String>() {
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            Window.alert("Error: " + caught.getMessage());
        }

        public void onSuccess(String s) {
            Window.alert("Success: " + s);
        }
    };

    databaseService.getProblems(callback);
}
```

I have set up the Service and the Async and then here is the code for the impl:

```
@Override
public String getProblems() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("Starting; ");
    try {           
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        builder.append("\nConnected!");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        builder.append("\nError SQLException: " + e.getMessage() + "; ");
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        builder.append("\nError InstantiationException: " + e.getMessage() + "; ");
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        builder.append("\nError IllegalAccessException: " + e.getMessage() + "; ");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        builder.append("\nError ClassNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage() + "; ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        builder.append("\nError OtherException: " + e.getMessage() + "; ");
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

When I run the code through Eclipse in development mode. It works and it able to connect and get the message:

```
Success: Starting;
Connected!
```

When I compile the code using GWT Complile and then trying launching the html out of the "war" folder I just get

```
Error: 0
```

This means that the caught.getMessage() is just "0". Why would is work through dev mode, but not once compiled.

Comment: Like it says: look at your server logs. How are you running it? One other option is to catch exceptions server side and return them as strings, but if you are trying to do serious client/server GWT, you need to figure out where your server logs are!

Comment: I fixed the error when running in dev mode. I had AppEngine running and the Google AppEngine is unable to resolve the driver for whatever reason, but when I disabled the app engine, was able to run it locally. Still having the issue once it is compiled. As for the server logs, I commit the compiled gwt and our server manager handles it from there. I will talk to him today to see if he can shed an light on the logs.